# G++ Needs version information from /usr/local/lib/libjansson.so.4

Tags: c++, g++, jansson

I am using G++ ( A linux command for compiling c++ code ) to compile a project, It spat out a error saying:

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libjansson.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/ld)

I first thought that the file didn't exist, so I checked the /usr/local/lib/ directory and the file was right there. I am pretty sure this means that the file is broken, as it says, there is no available version information inside the file.
I thought this was an error with OpenGL at first as I was using it, but when I used G++ without OpenGL it still gave the error. This must mean it is a G++ error.